# How to Finish Activity?

Tags: android

I am working with Recyclerview . i want to finish current Activity from its holder.when i click on item i want to open New Activity and Finish the current activity. pls help
my code is shown below`

```
public class GcmNotificationHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected TextView gcmMessage;
    protected TextView  messageTital;
    protected  TextView messageDate;
    protected ImageButton removeMessage;
    protected Context context;
    protected  List<Notification> notificationList;
    protected  boolean isRead = true;

    public GcmNotificationHolder(View itemView, List<Notification> notificationList, Context applicationContext) {
        super(itemView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
          context = applicationContext;
        this.gcmMessage = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.gcmMessage);
        this.messageTital=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.messagTital);
        this.messageDate=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.gcmMessageDate);
        this.notificationList = notificationList;
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), NotificationDescriptionActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("messageDescription", notificationList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getMessage());
        intent.putExtra("messageTital", notificationList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getMessagetital());
        intent.putExtra("messageDate", notificationList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getMessagedate());
         notificationList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId();
         notificationList.get(getAdapterPosition()).setIsRead(true);
        DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(context, "notification-db", null);
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        DaoMaster daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
        DaoSession daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
        NotificationDao notificationDao = daoSession.getNotificationDao();
        notificationDao.updateInTx(notificationList);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);

}}
```

Comment: call context.finish();

Comment: i tried this way but not able to call finish() in this way,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add next line in the end of the onClick():

```
((Activity)context).finish();
```

Answer (score 1):

When i pass Activity instance in holder Constructor its solve my problem